# Issue in generating Robotium Test report using Spoon

Tags: android, robotium, spoon

`com.squareup.spoon.SpoonTestRunListener.testFailed(Lcom/android/ddmlib/testrunner/TestIdentifier;Ljava/lang/String;)V`

Hi guys, I am using **"androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.1.9'"** dependency in my **build.gradle** file for generating report using Spoon. during `Spoon.screenshot(getActivity(),"screenName")`, test execution fails and gives error

`com.squareup.spoon.SpoonTestRunListener.testFailed(Lcom/android/ddmlib/testrunner/TestIdentifier;Ljava/lang/String;)V`

Comment: Could you please improve your post? Add code tags for example...

Comment: can you post full error log and  code ?